# DataStreamerにラズベリーパイは対応していますか？

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Arduinoは対応していると記載していましたが、DataStreamerにRaspberry Pieは対応していますか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ。
質問は [自分が経験した実際の問題に関する質問に主眼を置いてください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)どのようなことを試してみたか、そして具体的に何をしようとしているかを記述してください。
現在の質問内容だと単なる 丸投げです